# Oracle11gR2 silent install on centos6.5

Tags: oracle

I run ./runInstaller -silent -force -responseFile /data/app/oracle/etc/db_install.rsp and show some warnings

> [INS-13014] Target environment do not meet some optional requirements.

I check the log file and find some problems as following

> Validating Response File /data/app/oracle/etc/db_install.rsp
>   WARNING: Unable to find the namespace URI. Reason: Start of root element expected.
>   INFO: Setting Response file data to the Installer
>   WARNING: Unable to find the namespace URI. Reason: Start of root element expected.

I searched many sites and still can not deal with it.
Help me !

Comment: Try adding `-ignorePrereq` in your command.

Comment: I tried , but the issues still exist, this command just ignore it.